# Is tornado an async webserver?

Tags: python, asynchronous, block, tornado

I am learning to write a backend server that can handle thousands of connections.

I take a look on some sample code, but find it is still writing in sync logic.

For example: (take from http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html)

```py
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response1, response2 = yield [http_client.fetch(url1), http_client.fetch(url2)]
    print(response1.body, response2.body)
```

It is obvious that the `print` statement couldn't execute before getting the response of the two fetches, or else it will throw exception due to accessing not exist data.

Therefore, it must have a **block** between the last two lines, but, **block**, isn't tornado is highlight for non-block, async, event-driven... and then, could handle thousands of connections?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `tornado` is asynchronous. The example you're showing is a [`coroutine`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.coroutine); it's actually non-blocking, and releases control back to the tornado event loop at the `yield` call. Control only returns back to the `get` function when both `http_client.fetch` calls have actually completed.

These two examples are actually functionally equivalent in `tornado`:

```
class AsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        http_client.fetch("http://example.com",
                          callback=self.on_fetch)

    def on_fetch(self, response):
        do_something_with_response(response)
        self.render("template.html")
```

And a coroutine version:

```
class GenAsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield http_client.fetch("http://example.com")
        do_something_with_response(response)
        self.render("template.html")
```

Coroutines allow you to write asynchronous code that *looks* synchronous, which is more readable. When the above code hits the `yield`, `get` suspends and yields the [`Future`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.Future) object returned by `http_client.fetch` to the `gen.coroutine` decorator. The `gen.coroutine` decorator has magic in it that schedules the result of the `Future` returned by the `fetch` call to be passed back into `get` once its ready.

Comment: I am just making a Q&A style question... Please have a look on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

## Yes!

It is very likely to confuse with the two different pattern to use `yield` and `coroutine` between long running jobs and slow IO operations. I have just make a critical mistake on that.

- In long running jobs

  1. The `next()` method of its generator is repeatedly called, and do a unit of work every time.
  2. If have more than one `coroutine` running, the scheduler will call each `next()` method one by one, so it share CPU time between the jobs. So it is cooperative between the jobs, therefore called `coroutine`.
- In slow IO operations

  1. The `next()` method is called only once for each `yield` point.
  2. Once `yield` from the point doing IO operation, the IO operation **has delegate to OS kernel**. The scheduler will add a callback when IO operation has complete, which will call the `next()` method.
  3. And now it is a question for scheduler when to call the `next()` method. This is powered by OS level async feature, like `epoll`, `IOCP` to notiy scheduler when IO has complete.
  4. So the whole flow is, running to the point making IO, than `yield` to hand over execution. After IO has complete, it will continue execute by call `next()` from the scheduler.
  5. The effects of this control flow is exactly same with callback pattern, both are

     - run to a point dong IO
     - handover the execution so the process could do other jobs
     - IO has completed, continue running.
     - The only difference is one is continue to execute on the former function, and the other continue to a new callback function.

So, in summary:

- in long running jobs, the scheduler will call each `next()` method **once the process is idle**.
- in slow IO operations, the `next()` method is **called only once**, when the IO operations has finished.

I think if you realize that, you will understand that use `yield` and `coroutine` actually could have the same power with `callback`.

Comment: From the Tornado docs intro: "Tornado is a Python web framework and asynchronous networking library". While there are differences between async and non-blocking, you're a bit off here.

Comment: Tornado is both asynchronous and non-blocking. The doc page you linked to describes examples of tornado code that use callbacks and coroutines as asynchronous. Also,  the piece about lightweight threads not truly making things asynchronous is a reference to `gevent`, not coroutines.

Comment: The difference between "blocking" and "asynchronous" as described in the tornado docs is simply "does this code return before it's actually finished doing its work?" If it does, it's asynchronous. If it waits to finish its work prior to returning, it's blocking. Tornado allows you to write code in both of these styles. Now, tornado also allows you to make non-blocking I/O calls in functions that are synchronous, via coroutines, but those can easily be used in an asynchronous way (by not yielding from them).

Comment: Non-blocking synchronous functions do exist, but that means something different than you're saying here.  send() and recv() on a POSIX socket in non-blocking mode are synchronous in that if they return EAGAIN they do not continue working in the background (unlike Windows IOCP in which the socket calls are truly asynchronous).